# RestKit requests hang on HTTP errors

Tags: ios, restkit, afnetworking

I am trying to make my app handle HTTP client errors. Ideally, I would like to run a static method whenever such an error occurs, regardless of the request that caused it.

It seems that I am doing something wrong -- I have tried to add a `RKDynamicResponseDescriptor` to call the method, but it doesn't get called. Whenever my server responds with an error, the request never finishes (the network activity indicator keeps spinning and the `AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification` is never posted.)

I can reproduce the behavior by creating a new `AFHTTPRequest` request like this:

```
request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"events" parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
                    }
                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    }];
```

Neither the `success` nor the `failure` block is called. If I replace the first line with

```
request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

the blocks get called. How can I make RestKit handle the HTTP error response?

**Edit 1:** Apparently this happens in both cases when the server returns `401` with an authentication challenge. I have tried setting a breakpoint in `RKHTTPRequestOperation` in `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`, but it is not triggered. My Fiddler shows that only one request is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of fiddling, I think I have found the reason for this problem. The `AFUrlConnectionRequest` class implements the `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:`delegate method when SSL pinning is enabled. The implementation simply returns if the authentication challenge is not related to SSL.

From the [documentation of NSUrlConnectionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method allows the delegate to make an informed decision about connection authentication at once. If the delegate implements this method, it has no need to implement
>
> - connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:,
> - connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:,
> - connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:.
>
> In fact, these other methods are not invoked.

The methods will not be invoked, and thus RestKit never knows that the request resulted in HTTP error 401.

I solved the problem by removing this define, so the delegate method is not implemented:

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES_
```

Comment: did you report this bug?  I think I may be running into the same issue.